# I don't understand how domain name and URL redirect works

Tags: http, web-hosting

I bought a domaine name and made a website for my personal website. The website is currently a custom Mongoose  embedded server that loads HTML pages and shoots them when specific URLS are asked. My website works perfectly on my localhost on my port 8080. No problem there.

The problem is with my domain name. I bought a domain name from 1and1 because the first year was almost free and I like saving money. I went to the settings of my account. I clicked on my domain and did a URL redirect to my internet ip address. It works but the problem is that in the browser, you go from this :
www.georgeforeman.com  to hxxp://198.71.49.97:8080. I don't want my website to look like that. I also have the option with 1and1 to do a masked redirect but that's not what I want either because if you click a link on my website you keep my domain name everywhere you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking at the wrong setting. Redirect is like you wrote, to send the client to a new URL.

What you should be looking at is DNS, an a-record pointing at your ip.

Btw, you should try to change the webserver port to 80, since a client or DNS doesn't automatically transform ports.